# I/O error when using mail, activation and additional jar files in android stdio

Tags: android, email, android-studio, jar

I used the mail, activation and additional jar files in my application to send emails programmatically. The code to accomplish this has worked fine before, but as of late it has simply just stopped working. I am getting the following I/O errors when trying to send a mail from my app:

```
06-06 09:41:33.596 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.596 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.596 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
06-06 09:41:33.621 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.622 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.622 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
06-06 09:41:33.624 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.624 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.624 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
06-06 09:41:33.631 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.631 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.631 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.633 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.633 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error
06-06 09:41:33.633 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.636 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.636 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/qcom.fmradio.jar': I/O Error

                                                      [ 06-06 09:41:33.636 19502:20337 W/         ]
                                                      Unable to open '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': No such file or directory
06-06 09:41:33.636 19502-20337/neurosys.tgotracker W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error
```

I have the jar files in the libs directory in my application, and I use the following in my gradle file to be able to use the jars: `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])`.

As I said, this has always worked perfectly, but for some reason it just started throwing these errors.

I have deleted and re-installed Android Studio. I have also cleaned the project, restarted the IDE and rebuild the project several times. And I have tried to add the JAR files as modules instead of just directly using the libs folder. There are no errors in the code, so the JAR files are being detected by the IDE, but it's as if the files go missing right after I run the project (not really sure whats happening :().

1- Can you help me figure out what the problem is and how to fix it?

(or)

2- Are there any alternatives that I can use to send emails programmatically in android that do not require the use of JAR files?

If you require any additional information, please let me know. 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: So no-one is even going to try and help me??

Comment: did you find any solution to the above error ? 
W/art: Failed to open zip archive '/system/framework/oem-services.jar': I/O Error

Comment: @antroid Hey man, nah, I dropped these libs, could not get it to work. Instead went with https://elasticemail.com/support/http-api/send/. I had the option to, not sure if this is the case for you. Sorry that I cant be of more help regarding this issue

Comment: thanks for quick reply i dont see any error yet in the working  but was i ended up at your question wondering why am getting this error and what effects it putting on my project internal working/performance. theres a phonefield jar library i am using which might causing this IO error.